# Mapping a DbFunction to an InExpression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0, dbfunctions

In EF Core, I'm trying to map a custom function to an InExpression using the HasDbFunction functionality. I'm having trouble getting it to work as EF keeps complaining:

> 'The parameter 'enumerable' for the DbFunction 'StringEnumerableContains(IEnumerable,string)' has an invalid type 'IEnumerable'. Ensure the parameter type can be mapped by the current provider.'

My custom function is such:

```
public static bool StringEnumerableContains(IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string value)
{
    return enumerable.Contains(value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

And I'm trying to map it as so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var stringEnumerableContainsMethod = typeof(Util).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "StringEnumerableContains");
    modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(stringEnumerableContainsMethod).HasTranslation(args => new InExpression(args.Skip(1).First(), args.First(), false, null));       
}
```

I've also tried making the custom function `bool StringEnumerableContains(object enumerable, string value)` and it similarly says it cannot map type "object".

Background:
I need to map this custom db function because it needs to work in-memory as well as in EF Core. So the best way to achieve case-insensitivity in memory is by implementing it myself and in EF by mapping it to a normal IN expression (we use a case insensitive collation).

Any ideas for how to get this HasDbFunction mapping working correctly?

Comment: What database engine are you using? Can you please post a [mre]?

Comment: I'm using SqlServer.